# Accessing a view in each item of Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view whose each item has 2 TextView's and one Switch View. While populating the list, based on the content of one of the TextView, I want to make the switch visible or invisible.

```
This is what I want:
```

[image]

```
This is what I am getting:
```

[image]

To set the visibility of the switch, we can use `Switch.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. But I don't know where to use this line of code.

Comment: put your code here,  your adapter and the activity

Comment: Adapter: https://pastebin.com/cKgyEh1u
Fragment: https://pastebin.com/a9pfks3g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this method on your adapter:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LaunSubsItem launSubsItem = laundrySubsList.get(position);
        if(your_condition_here){
        holder. switchSubs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.tvWasherName.setText(launSubsItem.getDescription());
        holder.tvWasherStatTime.setText(launSubsItem.getTime());

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Can you explain what these overloaded methods exactly do, in lay-man terms.

Answer (score 2):

You have to maintain visibility in onBindViewHolder() method of RecyclerAdapter class

```
if (showSwitch) {
viewHolder.yourSwitch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
viewHolder.yourSwitch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LaunSubsItem launSubsItem = laundrySubsList.get(position);
    holder.tvWasherName.setText(launSubsItem.getDescription());
    holder.tvWasherStatTime.setText(launSubsItem.getTime());
    // Add this to your Adapter
    holder.switchSubs.setVisibility(tvWasherStatTime.getText().toString().contains("Available") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LaunSubsItem launSubsItem = laundrySubsList.get(position);
        holder.tvWasherName.setText(launSubsItem.getDescription());
        holder.tvWasherStatTime.setText(launSubsItem.getTime());
        if(launSubsItem.getTime().equals("Available")){
           viewHolder.switchSubs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
        viewHolder.switchSubs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update your `onBindViewHolder` as below:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LaunSubsItem launSubsItem = laundrySubsList.get(position);
    holder.tvWasherName.setText(launSubsItem.getDescription());
    holder.tvWasherStatTime.setText(launSubsItem.getTime());

    if (launSubsItem.getTime().contains("Available"))
        holder.switchSubs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        holder.switchSubs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```